# Computing the probability that a function of random variables takes particular values

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

If one rolls two fair die, the sum of the two rolls is most likely to be $7$, and $2$ and $12$ are very improbable. Likewise, if one averages two random numbers in the interval $[0,1]$, the most likely result is $0.5$ and the most unlikely are $0$ and $1$.

More generally, I would like to compute the continuous probability density $P\left(A=\frac{X+Y}{2}, \,\, B=X-Y\right)$ given independent continuous probability distributions $P(X),P(Y)$, and cannot seem to remember how to do this. I thought it went as
$$
P\left(A=\frac{X+Y}{2}, \,\, B=X-Y\right) \\= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 P(X)P(Y) \delta\left(A-\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)\delta\left(B-(X-Y)\right) dX dY
$$
but this cannot be right. For uniform $P(X),P(Y)$ it just gives either 0 or 1.

What is the proper way to calculate this probability? For that matter, for the life of me, I can't even remember what the right distribution for uniform $P(X),P(Y)$ in the above example is called.

Comment: For the dice case, it is easy: represent the distribution by a polynomial $P(x)=1/6 x^1 + \dots 1/6 x^6$ and calculate its square to get the distribution of the sum

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise. If $X$ and $Y$ are uniform on $[0,1]$, then $\mathbb P((X+Y)/2=0.5)=0$. If you're dealing with continuous RVs, you want to be talking about densities. Also are $a,b$ random variables, or are $x,y$ random variables? We usually use the convention of capitalising our random variable names to avoid this confusion...

Comment: jlammy, thank you - I've clarified that I meant the probability density, not the probability itself, and adopted the conventional notation. $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $A$ and $B$ are effectively functions of those random variables, for which I would like to calculate the PDF for $A$ and $B$ taking given values.
Damien, I've clarified that I'm interested in the continuous case, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix}=M\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}.$$
Observe that $\det M=-1$ and $M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1/2\\1&-1/2\end{pmatrix}$. Then the density of $(A,B)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f_{A,B}(a,b)=\frac{1}{\lvert\det M\rvert}f_{X,Y}(M^{-1}y)&=f_{X,Y}(a+b/2,a-b/2)\\
&=f_X(a+b/2)\cdot f_Y(a-b/2).
\end{align*}
This is a special case of the general change of variables formula for integrals. Since our transformation is linear, the Jacobian is just $\lvert J\rvert=\det(M^{-1})$.

The marginal density of $A$ is
$$f_A(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{A,B}(a,b)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}b=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(a+b/2)f_Y(a-b/2)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}b.$$
When $X$ and $Y$ are both $\mathcal U[0,1]$, we have $f_X(x)=\mathbf1(0\leq x\leq1)$, so the integrand is positive iff $a\in[0,1]$ and $\max\{-a,a-1\}\leq b/2\leq\min\{1-a,a\}$. Then we have
$$f_A(a)=\int_{\max\{-a,a-1\}}^{\min\{1-a,a\}}1\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}b=2\min\{1-a,a\},$$
which is clearly maximised for $a=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you, but where does that integral transformation come from? How is this done in general? It would be helpful to have a reference or something describing how this process works. As mentioned in the question, I don't even remember the names for these things and can't look them up until I do.

Comment: It's not (really) a result about probability -- it's a calculus result for changing variables for integrals. See for example [here](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=484&lmm=0). Then you can look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability) for how this applies to random variables. The technique should be in any good probability text of this level, e.g. Grimmett and Stirzaker's *Probability and Random Processes* Section 4.7

Comment: Thank you - as it turns out, I had the right idea in the first place, but played too fast and loose and forgotten that the limits of integration would change the marginal probability after integrating out $s$. I'd essentially been using [a different way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) of transforming between coordinates.